# Kibana Windows 10 : EACCES permission denied

Tags: windows, kibana

I try to use Kibana on Windows 10 (yeah, I know).
I think I put both yml right:
elasticsearch uri: localhost:9201
kibana uri: localhost:5601

When I start Kibana in Windows I get:

```
    {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-03-06T20:25:28Z","tags":
["fatal","root"],"pid":2844,"message":"{ 
    Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:5601\n
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1260:19)\n    
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1325:12)\n
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (net.js:1458:7)\n
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:62:10)\n  
    code: 'EACCES',\n  
    errno: 'EACCES',\n  
    syscall: 'listen',\n  
    address: '127.0.0.1',\n  
    port: 5601 }"}
```

I tried to setup permission to full access on the kibana.bat file.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hi seems your port is already in use.

Also open your kibana URL to check whether it is assigned already.

Check your port and kill it inorder to use.

OR

Open your kibana config yaml file, uncomment the port info and change the port.

I had the similar issue and got solved by trying this way. Hope it helps.